# xml only takes one element (XML parsing in iOS)

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing

I have to parse an XML over and display the data out in a table-view.

This is how my XML looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FacLocation>
    <Facility Type="Project Room">
        <Code>L435</Code>
        <Code>L509C</Code>
    </Facility>
</FacLocation>
```

I have to display L435 and L509C in a tableview cell.

But the XML only stores the last record which is L509C.

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath;

RoomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RoomCell"];

```
if (!cell)
{
    cell =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RoomCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSLog(@"This is NSLog!");

Rooms *rc = [self.roomsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.RoomLabel setText:[rc roomCode]];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.75 green:0.93 blue:1 alpha:1];
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.55 green:0.55 blue:0.55 alpha:1]];

return cell;
```

I have this in my didEndElement method;

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Code"])
    {
        tempRoom.roomCode = self.tempString;
        NSLog(@"tempString (Module Room): %@", tempString);
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Facility"])
    {
        [self.roomsArray addObject:tempRoom];
    }
```

Now the problem is that it only reads the last record. Which meant it only reads L509C. It discards the record of L435. Is there any way I can keep both records and display them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these value in array like this

```
[self.roomsArray addObject:@"L435"];
[self.roomsArray addObject:@"L509C"];

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.roomsArray count];
}
```

After edited

```
 if (!cell)
    {
        cell =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RoomCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSLog(@"This is NSLog!");

// ------------- Change here
    [cell.RoomLabel setText:[self.roomsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.75 green:0.93 blue:1 alpha:1];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.55 green:0.55 blue:0.55 alpha:1]];

    return cell;
```

Comment: I have to read the names of the rooms from the XML sheet. Is there anyway I could do it without having it to be hard-coded? @DharmbirChoudhary

Comment: You should add object to array in foundCharacter xml's delegate method.

Comment: thanks. but i have another problem. I have updated my question. Is there any way I can keep both records? Because this method I'm using only reads the last record which is L509C. Thank you. @DharmbirChoudhary

Comment: Thanks so much. I've edited my codes as you've said it. But it comes out an error. unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6896810, Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Rooms isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6896810' @DharmbirChoudhary

Comment: have you changed according to me in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method

Comment: Yep, I have changed it into [cell.RoomLabel setText:[self.roomsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] but there's an error. @DharmbirChoudhary

Comment: i think dear you are doing little mistake but you knw we are developer so dnt have enough time so plz try to do your self its a little mistake.All the best dear...

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Thanks so much for your help anyway. Thank you! @DharmbirChoudhary

Comment: Its k my dear try to understnd me...I think you can understand it very well if you developer.